# Integral ${\Large\int}\frac{x+3}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

${\Large\int}\frac{x+3}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

i tried substituting $t=\sqrt{x+2}$

$x=t^2-2$

$dx=2tdt$

i get here:
$\frac{(t^2+1)^2}{4}$
but then i have to re-convert $t$ with $x$, and it's just a mess.

EDIT: $\sqrt{x+2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}}$, when i do the integral i get:

$2/3\sqrt{(x+2)^3}+2\sqrt{x+2}$

but wolfram gives me a different result, how?:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%28x%2B2%29%2B1%2Fsqrt%28x%2B2%29

Comment: it may be easier just to substitute $u = x+2$ and then use the power rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why you don't try this $$\frac{x+3}{\sqrt{x+2}}=\\\frac{x+2+1}{\sqrt{x+2}}=\\\frac{\sqrt{(x+2)^2}+1}{\sqrt{x+2}}=\\\sqrt{x+2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Putting $x+3=x+2+1$ in denominator will help you

Comment: I think you mean numerator..